# Python smartsql compile insert statement

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite, sqlbuilder

I want to use sqlbuilder (https://sqlbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library for building native queries to sqlite. There is my code for inserting data:

```
import sqlite3
from sqlbuilder.smartsql import Q, T
from sqlbuilder.smartsql.dialects.sqlite import compile


if __name__ == '__main__':
    connection = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')

    with connection:
        connection.execute('CREATE TABLE temp (t TEXT, i INTEGER)')

        insert = compile(Q(T.temp).insert({T.temp.t: 'text', T.temp.i: 1}))
        sql, params = insert

        connection.execute(
            sql, params
        )

    connection.close()
```

This code does not work, because `compile` produces incorrect sql and params for sqlite:
`('(?, (?, ?))', ['INSERT INTO "temp" ("i", "t") VALUES (%s, %s)', 1, 'text'])`, and I got the error: `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error`

Interesting, there is not problems with compiling and executing `select` statements.

**UPDATE:**

Code for select statements and it's work:

```
import sqlite3
from sqlbuilder.smartsql import Q, T
from sqlbuilder.smartsql.dialects.sqlite import compile

if __name__ == '__main__':
    connection = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')

    with connection:
        connection.execute('CREATE TABLE temp (t TEXT, i INTEGER)')

        select = compile(Q(T.temp).fields('*'))
        print(select)  # ('SELECT * FROM `temp`', [])
        sql, params = select

        connection.execute(
            sql, params
        )

    connection.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Answer emended*

From the [python doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) for sqlite3 APIs:

> Usually your SQL operations will need to use values from Python
>   variables. You shouldn’t assemble your query using Python’s string
>   operations because doing so is insecure; it makes your program
>   vulnerable to an SQL injection attack (see https://xkcd.com/327/ for
>   humorous example of what can go wrong).
>
> Instead, use the DB-API’s parameter substitution. Put ? as a
>   placeholder wherever you want to use a value, and then provide a tuple
>   of values as the second argument to the cursor’s execute() method.
>   (Other database modules may use a different placeholder, such as %s or
>   :1.) For example:
>
> *# Never do this -- insecure!*
>   `symbol = 'RHAT' c.execute("SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol = '%s'" % symbol)`
>
> *# Do this instead*
>   `t = ('RHAT',) c.execute('SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol=?', t)`

The returned value of `` insert` `('(?, (?, ?))', ['INSERT INTO "temp" ("i", "t") VALUES (%s, %s)', 1, 'text']) `` indicates `sqlbuilder` is trying to take this advice. What remains is to how to do the string interpolation to put it into valid sqlite syntax. Turns out the `result` argument to the `Q` constructor will do just that.

`insert = Q(T.temp,result=Result(compile=compile)).insert({T.temp.t: 'text', T.temp.i: 1})` will return a tuple that is "SQL ready", ie: `` ('INSERT INTO `temp` (`i`, `t`) VALUES (?, ?)', [1, 'text']) ``. Now you see the '%s' have been replaced by '?'. Don't forget to import `Result`.

Comment: You are not right about `compile` and instance of `Q`, please see the sqlbuilder doc. And yes, `compile` returns a tuple with sql and array of params, In question I provided this tuple for compiling insert statement, and there is the problem - sql in this tuple is not correct for sqlite, but I dont know why. I make an update for question and provides compiling and executing select statement - and compiling select statement is work

Comment: Sorry about that! Thank you for pointing out the inaccuracies in the answer. I have edited the answer with correction.

Comment: Thanks! But main question is why need to use `result`? And I tried using `result` for select statements - not working (`sql, params = Q(T.temp, result=Result(compile=compile)).fields('*')` raises `NotImplementedError`)

Comment: The reason to use `result` on INSERT is because `compile` does not give proper INSERT syntax without it. The SELECT does not work with `sql, params =`. It does work with `select =` [some var name]. I do not know why it gives `NotImplementedError`.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for solving my problem!